# WebDev.WebServer.EXE Crashes After VS 2008 SP1 Install

Tags: asp.net, webserver

Since, for various reasons, I can't use IIS for an ASP.NET website I'm developing, I run Cassini from the command line to test the site.  However, after installing Visual Studio 2008 SP1, I get a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException when I try to start up the web server.  Is anyone else having this problem, and if so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Is there anything in the Application section of the event log?
- Have you tried using a different port?
- Per [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1309348/2575545.aspx), try:

  > Unbind from Visual Source safe, delete the web project from the solution, rename the folder where the website is stored and then re add to the solution as an existing web site and then bind to source safe again.

There may be some incorrect info in your `.suo` or `.sln` file. You can safely rename the former, as it is user-specific (**s**olution **u**ser **o**ptions); the latter (the **s**o**l**utio**n** itself) would be a bit more of a hassle to recreate.

Comment: Using a different port worked for me.  (3000 = good, 4242 = no good)  Which is good, because unbinding really wasn't an option.  The event log messages were very cryptic and not helpful at all.  Hex codes and such.

Comment: I had the same problem.  Deleting the .sou was my fix.  Thanks!

Comment: I also had the same problem, but starting from command line not from VS. First you should chek the open ports by using this command: `netstat -anob`, then start WebDev.WebServer.exe defining a non opened port using the switch `/port`.